# How to find out all the popping out possibilities of two stacks?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, stack

There are two stack here:

```
A: 1,2,3,4 <- Stack Top
B: 5,6,7,8
```

A and B will pop out to other two stacks: C and D.

```
Example: 
 pop(A),push(C),pop(B),push(D).
 If an item have been popped out , it must be pushed to C or D immediately.
```

So, is there an algorithm to find out all the possibilities of C and D ?

Many thanks !

Comment: What would yoy mean by possibilities? Stack A can be popped only to give: 4,3,2,1 and B to 8,7,6,5.  Do you mean you are trying to find the various ways you can pop out A and B, (like, pop(A),pop(B),pop(A),pop(A),pop(B)..) and such?

Comment: @Amit , That's exactly what i mean , sorry for the confusing.

Comment: can A and B have repeated elements? By repeated I mean same element is there in both A and B....if yes, do we have to count the unique combinations of C and D?

Comment: @RaviGupta No, All the items are unique.

Comment: Are you alternating between pushing to C and D, or can they be pushed in any order?  Do A and B always start out with the same number of elements?  Do C and D need to end up with the same number of elements?

Comment: For anyone interested : http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2257/generating-number-of-possibilites-of-popping-two-stacks-to-two-other-stacks/2360#2360

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a list of all possible pops of the stack and then simulate:

However, there are going to be duplicates, consider the case when there are only two elements on each stack. If a is pushed to c and b to d, it doesn't matter which order they are pushed.

```
def simulate(steps):
    source={'a':range(4),'b':range(4,8)}
    res = {'c':"",'d':""}; 
    for i,step in enumerate(steps):
        res[step[1]]+=str(source[step[0]].pop())
    # this is what each stack will look like
    return res['c']+'-'+res['d']  

def steps(a_left,b_left):
    ret = []
    if a_left>0:
        substeps = steps(a_left-1,b_left)
        ret.extend( [ x + [('a','c')] for x in substeps] )
        ret.extend( [ x + [('a','d')] for x in substeps] )
    if b_left>0:
        substeps = steps(a_left,b_left-1)
        ret.extend(  [ x + [('b','c')] for x in substeps] )
        ret.extend(  [ x + [('b','d')] for x in substeps] )
    if(len(ret)==0):
        return [[]]
    return ret;
```

And the result:

```
>>> [x for x in steps(1,1)]
[[('b', 'c'), ('a', 'c')], [('b', 'd'), ('a', 'c')], [('b', 'c'), ('a', 'd')], [
('b', 'd'), ('a', 'd')], [('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c')], [('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c')], [('
a', 'c'), ('b', 'd')], [('a', 'd'), ('b', 'd')]]
>>> [simulate(x) for x in steps(1,1)]
['73-', '3-7', '7-3', '-73', '37-', '7-3', '3-7', '-37']
>>> len(set([simulate(x) for x in steps(4,4)]))
5136
```

If we consider two stacks with only one target stack, we can find the number of unique stacks at (2*n)!/(n!)^2.  This is the same as the number of permutations of 8 elements, 4 of which are 'A's and 4 of which are 'B's.  We can then assign them to each individual stack by dividing them up in to subsets - the number of subsets with N unique numbers per stack is going to be 2^(2^n)

```
(2^(2*n))/((2*n)!/(n!)^2)
```

I don't see a way to generate these more efficiently, though.

Answer (score 0):

I got an idea but don't know whether it's correct:

Setup an stack which have 8 bits, 1 means A pop and 0 means B pop ( Just make sure there are four 1 and four 0).

So the answer turns to be find out all the possibilities of an 8 bit array combinations.

And then iterate the 8 bit to pop out A or B.

Here's the code:

```
public class Test {
public static void generate(int l, int[] a) {
    if (l == 8) {
        if (isValid(a)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                System.out.print(a[i]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            a[l] = i;
            generate(++l, a);
            --l;
        }
    }
}

// the combination must have four 0 and four 1.
public static boolean isValid(int[] a) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] == 0) count++;
    }
    if (count != 4) return false;
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    generate(0, new int[8]);
}
```

}

Comment: To do it this way, you would need to create a bit array of length 16 - From A/B To B/C.  This is an expensive algorithm O(2^(2^n)) where n is the number of elements in each stack

Answer (score 0):

The contents of C and D can be written out as a sequence of four A's and four B's, in any order.

> AABABBBA *(represents popping A twice, then B once, then A once, etc.)*

There are exactly **8 choose 4** such sequences.  So just [iterate over every such sequence](http://www.codingthewheel.com/archives/exhaustively-enumerating-combinations-and-permutations-in-code) *("combinations without repetition")* to get your answer.

Comment: This doesn't tell you the possibilities of C and D though

Comment: @dfb: Yes, it does.  For example, read the first four letters as "pop(A),push(C); pop(A),push(D); pop(B),push(C); pop(A),push(D)" etc.

Comment: ?? - where does the first letter in the sequence indicate it should go to C and not D.  I read the problem as you can choose both at each step

Comment: @dfb: Oh, I see; we seemed to have interpreted the question differently.  I thought he was alternating between pushing to C and D.  I'll ask in the comments above.